# Form View Based on Access

Tags: odoo-9, odoo-10

How can I hide form view based on users access?

For example : If I log with **user1**

- I can see all customers (created by me and user2) in kanban end tree views.
- In form view only view my customers.

Comment: I'm not sure if this can be achieved with a single menu/list view. Typically you can either view a record or you can't. Viewing would include seeing the record in the tree view.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to achieve this is by updating the form view itself. You would put all of the contents into a `div` and hide it if the `user_id` (or whichever field you want to base the rule in) is someone else.

Effectively, it would look something like this:

```
<div attrs="{'invisible': [('user_id', '!=', user.id)]}">
    # normal form view fields and formatting
</div>
```

If the `user_id` field does not default to the logged in user, it's possible that the form fields would hide by default when creating a new record. You would be able to bypass it with something like this (which allows you to see records that aren't assigned to a user) instead:

```
<div attrs="{'invisible': [('user_id', 'not in', [user.id, False])]}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to make two groups for that.
First one is for admin and second is for users.

In kanban and tree, you have to give the fields admin rights or apply group 1 on tree and kanban view.

In form view you have to give the second group so, it will perfectly work as per your requirements.